# Converter/styles selector without binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, valueconverter

Is it possible to use a converter/style selector without having to use databinding?

I want the style of my object to change if a certain value is reached.

Here is what i have

```
    <Border Name="watch0_0Border" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource clockBorderStyle}">
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource clockStackPanelStyle}">
            <TextBlock Name="watch0_0Time" Style="{StaticResource clockTimerStyle}">07:45:23</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="watch0_0Description" Style="{StaticResource clockTextStyle}" Text="{Binding ElementName=watch0_0WorkDescription, Path=Text}"></TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Name="watch0_0Pause" Margin="5" Click="watch0_0Pause_Click">Pause</Button>
                <Button Name="watch0_0SetNewTime" Margin="5" Click="watch0_0SetNewTime_Click">Set new time</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBox Name="watch0_0Hours" Margin="5">0</TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="watch0_0Minutes" Margin="5">0</TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="watch0_0Seconds" Margin="5">0</TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="watch0_0WorkDescription" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5">Work description</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

I want to canhe the background of the border when the times goes under 0.

Comment: This depends on how the value is changed (eg. is this an automatically updated value or is it changed by the user). How about using a trigger/datatrigger/eventtrigger?

Comment: Why you do not like a binding? You can use it with a custom value (not bound from a DataContext)

Comment: I usualy also use binding but this is just for a quick project. I want to change the background when a timer goes under zero.

Comment: @FireFly3000 : provide some XAML you've already created and ViewModel properties you want to handle

Comment: I don't see any bindings to something like TimerValuie, also try out Commands instead of event handlers... in this way you can decouple logic from View my moving handling logic from code behind to something like ViewModel in MVVM o

Comment: No that is because I don't want to use binding right now. As my question also said ;)

Comment: Binding a datatrigger to a view model that exposes a timer expired property seems the way to go here - why is that not suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your timer has access to main window (which can access watch0_0Border) or watch0_0Border direct (by passing these in when timer was created) then you should just be able to use the UI dispatcher to set watch0_0Border.BorderBrush (or whatever property) when timer hits zero.

Comment: Just what I was looking for... I don't know why I didn't think of that my self :S